# Mean of "Rate" variables in clustering

Tags: clustering, mean

My variable list includes: MMR (maternal mortality per 100000 live births)  of different countries. While performing clustering by hierarchical method, the cluster mean (as reported by stata) is just sum of the cluster numbers divided by the number of observations within the cluster, while it should be (total maternal death within a cluster/ total live births in a cluster)*100000.
How can I get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use weighted vectors, with the weight set to the population size. For some linkage strategies, the cluster weights are taken into account.

Note that clusters in hierarchical clustering can be non-convex, and the mean may be outside the cluster.